# Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted]

Tags: tokens, error, poa

i have created this contract

https://etherscan.io/address/0xfecf0e91a193e8511ac83d8effda34ae4278f491#code

but the problem is when i try to contribute to crowdsale it showing an error, (Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted] )

btw i have put my 2 addresses as whitelist addresses, i can contribute to crowdsale only with these two addresses when i try with other addresses always it failed.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc54f702c784785174d7dcba4d643c05f87e43d945adb6cc3290e124cf05f3716

im thinking the issue is in here (function `investInternal`):

```
 if(!earlyParticipantWhitelist[receiver].status) {
      throw;
 }
```

Receiver (the caller of the buy method), is not on the `earlyParticipantWhitelist`.

please help me if someone knows the what is the error, how to change this and how to change the contact.

Comment: You are using a very old version of the solidity compiler, your contract do not have a fallback function to accept payment, and none of the methods is payable.